# problem while caching java applets for offline

Tags: java, applet

we had to run java applets on offline from a html page that was captured by google gears.
 for caching applet we used cache_archive & cache_version. but it did not seem working

here i pointed out 3 traced errors:

```
error 1:
network: Cache entry not found [url: http: sample.net/applets/welcome.jar,
```

version: 1.1.3.2]
    network: Connecting http: sample.net/applets/welcome.jar?version-id=1.1.3.2
  with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting socket: sample.net with proxy=DIRECT
    java.net.UnknownHostException: sample.net

```
error 2:
network: Cache entry not found
```

[url: http: sample.net/com.transmdi.TransMDI/com/GeneralApplet.class, version: null]

```
error 3:
/class.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket: sample.net with proxy=DIRECT
load: class com.GeneralApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.GeneralApplet.class
```

system configuration:
Ubuntu,firefox 3.5.7 & jre 1.6

here OBJECT/EMBED tag we used:

```
***object-tag*** classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
```

name="generalapp" height="0" width="0" 
    param value="com.GeneralApplet.class" name="CODE"
    param value="welcome.jar" name="archive"
    param value="welcome.jar" name="cache_archive"
    param value="1.1.3.5" name="cache_version" 
    param value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" name="type"

***comment-tag***

***embed-tag***  archive="welcome.jar" cache_archive="welcome.jar" 
  cache_version="1.1.3.5" codebase="../applets/" code="com.GeneralApplet"
  type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" name="generalapp" height="0" width="0"

***comment-tag***
   ***object-tag***

any help

Thanks
Yohi

Answer (score 0):

**embed** archive="welcome.jar"  archive="welcome.jar"

Is this supposed to be listed twice?

Also look at **[this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet-caching.html)** for selecting the cache option whether your using the browser or the plugin to cache the jar.

cache_option and cache_archive can only be specified once per EMBED/OBJECT tag. In addition, both attributes must be specified. If either cache_archive or cache_option are missing, Java Plug-in will treat the applet normally using the archive attribute.

More on the use of the Archive tag here

[Applet Tag Params](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html)

Comment: while editing tags i was wrongly posted the "archive" twice....
actually above tag was working fine in windows firefox when offline .. but, for linux the applet was not getting loaded after disconnecting network..

when offline applets are getting loaded properly in linux?.. please  tell me what was wrong with above code..

i tried a lot but not yet solved ...